# How to remove striped attribute from inner table in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, html-table, bootstrap-4

I have used `.table-striped` class for one of my tables. Unfortunately, I use more tables inside this table, which also became striped.

How to make inner tables be not striped?

Comment: Can you post the code please?

Comment: Why can't you give that table an ID, then use jquery to remove the class?

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a new style much like `.table-striped` and use the immediate child selector [`>`] [MDN link][1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) so it only selects the immediate `tr` and not all the `tr` children in the table?

```
.table-striped__immediate-only > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
```